# Why doesn't the WYSIWYG support H1-H6 tags?

Tags: wysiwyg

I'm just wondering how i can have a client write normal paragraph text separated by headers if there is no header capability in the WYSIWYG editor, at least not that i've been able to locate?

Answer (score 3):

Enable the *kitchen sink*, the button in the upper right corner of this screenshot:

[image]

You get a dropdown now with special entries for headings.